# Change a range for a specific series in a chart using vba

Tags: excel, vba, series, excel-charts

I am trying to repurpose an existing series that I have in multiple charts-there are well over a hundred charts in one worksheet, so trying to do via vba. Warning: Very new to VBA!

In each chart, Series 1 references data in columns A-C, but different rows. So for example Series 1 in chart 1 is A1:C1, and Series 1 in Chart 2 is A10:C10. Is there a way using vba to change Series 1 in all of my charts to refer to columns D:F, without changing the reference to the rows? (so end result would be Series 1 in chart 1 D1:F1, and Chart 2 D10:F10)?

Thank you in advance.